# Como fazer cópia de objetos em java

Tags: java

Tem como fazer uma cópia de objeto em Java?

```
MinhaClasse mc = new MinhaClasse();

MinhaClasse mc2 = mc;
```

Mas queria fazer alterações em `mc2` sem afetar `mc`.

Comment: Tentou utlizar a classe Cloneable do Java? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Comment: MinhaClasse mc = new MinhaClasse();
MinhaClasse mc2 = new MinhaClasse();
já não resolveria

Comment: não resolveria por que eu queria que mc2 tivesse os mesmo valores de mc, sem que eu tivesse que preencher os campos novamente manualmente

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basta sobrescrever o método [`Object#clone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29), mas a sua classe precisa implementar a interface [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html):

> Por convenção, as classes que implementam esta *interface* devem substituir `Object.clone` (que é protegida) por um método público.

Utilizando o exemplo de `MinhaClasse` utilizado na pergunta, esta ficaria assim:

```
public class MinhaClasse implements Cloneable {

    // Atributos e métodos 

    @Override
    public MinhaClasse clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (MinhaClasse) super.clone();
    }
}
```

Desse modo bastaria chamar o método `clone` desta forma:

```
MinhaClasse meuObjeto = new MinhaClasse();
MinhaClasse meuOutroObjeto = meuObjeto.clone();
```

Answer (score 4):

O método mais *correto* para criar cópias, duplicar ou clonar objetos é implementando o método [`clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) **e** a interface [Clonable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html). Isto permite definir exatamente os valores que serão copiados e até clonar objeto contidos no objeto principal, se for o caso.

Entretanto, dependendo do contexto, existem outras alternativas que podem ser viáveis. Por exemplo, se a ideia é apenas copiar um Java Bean com atributos simples, *getters* e *setters*, então é possível o método [`cloneBean()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#cloneBean(java.lang.Object)) da biblioteca **Apache Commons BeansUtils**. Existe também o método [`copyProperties()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) que copia os atributos de um objeto para outro.

Outra opção, se a classe for serializável, é executar a serialização da mesma seguida da desserialização. Pronto, você tem uma cópia exata.

Claro que não é recomendável utilizar os dois métodos mencionados acima para um caso tão simples, mas eles podem ser úteis para o desenvolvimento de frameworks ou funcionalidades bem específicas.

Um dos cenários onde já usei isso foi em um sistema que tinha, literalmente, centenas de Java Beans em constante mudança. Não era viável criar e manter atualizado o método `clone()` em todas as classes.

Comment: Lamento discordar, mas o método clone não é "o método mais correcto" para criar cópias. Tudo aquilo que dizes ser vantagem do método clone é possível com o construtor de cópia e sem a necessidade de implementar uma interface . Não vou votar negativamente porque penso que a sugestão de usar o cloneBean é interessante. :)

Comment: @bruno A linguagem possui um padrão muito claro e definido para criar cópias, o método `clone`. Só porque é possível fazer de outra forma não significa que não exista um padrão.

Comment: @bruno Na verdade, do ponto de vista de Padrões de Projetos, o construtor não é uma boa prática porque você fica muito dependente da implementação. Um método *factory* seria mais interessante, mas do ponto de vista de abstração e polimorfismo, o `clone` é o mais genérico. Dependendo da aplicação das cópias, o clone permite aplicar o padrão de projeto [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern), o que não é possível com um contrutor.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, basta definires o método Constructor

```
class MinhaClasse {
  private String str;

  public MinhaClasse (MinhaClasse outro) {
    this.str= outro.str; // tens acesso directo
  }
}
```

Todos os objects possuem um método clone que por defeito permite a copia de objectos. As boas práticas ditam que deves definir o teu método de cópia.

Após a definição deste método é simples copiar os objectos. Podes simplesmente fazer o seguinte:

```
MinhaClasse mC = new MinhaClasse();
....(fazer algo com o objecto)
mc.Update();

MinhaClasse mC2(mc);
....(fazer algo com o objecto)
mC2.Update()  <- esta alteração apenas irá afectar mC2!
```

Em resposta ao teu comentário. Caso a tua classe MinhaClasse tenha como membros outras classes que não de tipo primitivo (int, string, ...) então essas classes também deverão ter definidos construtores de cópia. Por exemplo.

```
class ClasseA {

   private ClasseB b;
   private String str;

   ClasseA (ClasseA outro) {
      this.b(outro.b) (aqui tens que garantir que a ClasseB possui um constructor de copia ou método =)  
      this.str= outro.str; // tens acesso directo     
      }
}
```

EDIT:

A todos aqueles que estão a sugerir implementar a interface Cloneable e definir o método clone() eu sugiro a leitura dos seguintes artigos. Principalmente a leitura do Effective Java:

- ["Copy Constructor versus Cloning"](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)
- ["Effective Java Effective cloning"](http://adtmag.com/articles/2000/01/18/effective-javaeffective-cloning.aspx)

Deixo aqui apenas mais uma citação do Josh Bloch

> "The Cloneable interface was intended as a mixin interface for objects
>   to advertise that they permit cloning. Unfortunately it fails to serve
>   this purpose ... This is a highly atypical use of interfaces and not
>   one to be emulated ... In order for implementing the interface to have
>   any effect on a class, it and all of its superclasses must obey a
>   fairly complex, unenforceable and largely undocumented protocol"

Comment: O que fazer quando a classe referencia outras classes dentro dela? As referencias ainda estão apontando para os mesmos objetos. Eu vou ter que programar o clone recursivo?

Comment: Sim, deverá fazer isso recursivamente e será um pouco trabalhoso. Você já parou pra analisar com mais calma o seu negócio pra verificar se uma cópia de um objeto é realmente necessária? Não existem outras alternativas no seu design pra evitar ter que trabalhar com cópias?

Comment: No meu projeto, vou ter enviar um objeto via json, mas tem coisa nesse objeto que eu não queria mandar. Por isso pensei em copiar o objeto, deletar o que eu não queria enviar e fazer o json dessa copia. Vou pensar em outra maneira de fazer isso, mas acho que vou ter que copiar os dados que eu não quero enviar, deletar da classe e colocá-los de volta após a criação do json

Comment: Não é mais fácil dar um `new` em um objeto e settar apenas as propriedades que você precisa a partir do objeto original? Ou filtrar na criação do json?

Comment: O livro Effective Java é muito bom, mas só porque o autor cita alguns problemas e desvantagens do uso de uma determinada funcionalidade da linguagem, isso não significa absolutamente que ela não deve ou não possa ser usado em  diversos cenários mais simples, como é o caso de Java Beans simples. Outros capítulos do livro fazem o mesmo, entrando em discussões bem interessantes e profundas como no caso das diferentes possíveis implementações do padrão Singleton. O importante é entender que cada abordagem tem suas vantagens e desvantagens.

Comment: Um dos grandes problemas de clonar com construtor é o alto acoplamento com a implementação. E se forem feitas implementações polimórficas, os mesmos exatos problemas citados pelo autor podem ocorrer.

Comment: @utluiz, antes de mais obrigado pelo comentário. É importante quando podemos debater este género de questões aqui e podemos participar nesta troca de informação. No comentário que eu fiz à tua resposta, eu referi isso mesmo, que por exemplo o cloneBeans é uma boa alternativa para shallow-cloning. No entanto, mantenho a minha opinião. A interface cloneable tem falhas no seu desenho, basta procurar por essa internet fora que não faltam artigos a indicar o mesmo e a sugerir alternativas. Para mim o problema é apenas o dizer que o melhor método para copiar objectos é o clone(), apenas isso.