# Clonando uma classe

Tags: java, android, clone

Estou "tentando" clonando a seguinte classe:

```
public class CadHorario implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    private int cdHorario;
    ...
    private Date horarioInicio;
    private Date horarioFim;
    private DiasDaSemana diasDaSemana;
    ...

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Classe DiasDaSemana:

```
public class DiasDaSemana implements Cloneable {

    private boolean seg;
    private boolean ter;
    private boolean qua;
    private boolean qui;
    private boolean sex;
    private boolean sab;
    private boolean dom;
    ...

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
         return super.clone();
    }
}
```

alguns atributo está clonando, mais outros como `DiasDaSemana` não está clonando.
Estou clonando assim:

```
CadHorario clonado = (CadHorario) horario.clone();
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: [Como fazer cópia de objetos em java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60813/3117), talvez te ajude (talvez não).

Answer (score 0):

Olhando o que você fez, não há nada de errado. Só duas observações: entendo que não seria necessário também implementar a interface Cloneable na classe DiasDaSemana; e por convenção faria a seguinte adaptação no metodo clone:

```
@Override
public CadHorario clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
   return (CadHorario) super.clone();
}
```

Caso algum atributo da classe não tenha sido clonado, provavelmente é por não ter sido instanciado previamente.

Finalmente, se ainda assim você não conseguir resolver o problema pode utilizar bibliotecas como **BeansUtils** (Apache commons) ou você mesmo implementar um construtor para isso, exemplo:

```
public CadHorario(CadHorario horario){
   this.cHorario = horario.cHorario;
   ...
}

CadHorario clone = new CadHorario(horario);
```