# Atribuição e atualização de variavel static em java

Tags: java, static

Estou com um problema com uma variável Static. No código eu atribuo a uma variável que não é static, o conteúdo de uma variável Static. Depois eu atualizo a variável estática, só que a variável que recebeu o valor de static lá no inicio está atualizando junto e não entendo pq esta acontecendo isso. 
Tipo, eu quero guardar o valor da variável static em outra variável no inicio do código, pra poder usar depois. Mas esta outra variável está atualizando junto e não entendo por que.

```
public class Jogador {
    public static Heroi jogador;   
    public static Item armaEquipada;
    public static Item defesaEquipada;
    public static Personagem oponente;
    public static int IdSala;

    public Jogador(){
        jogador = new Heroi("Optimus", 10, 100, 50, 100);
        oponente = new Vilao("", 0, 0);

    }
}
```

Aqui estão os tipos das variáveis:

```
public Heroi EstadoAnteriorHeroi = null;
public Personagem EstadoAnteriorVilao;
```

Aqui estão as atribuições:

```
EstadoAnteriorVilao = Jogador.oponente; 
EstadoAnteriorHeroi = Jogador.jogador; // guarda os atributos anteriores do heroi se ele morrer e ainda tiver vidas;
System.out.println("Nome vilao: "+EstadoAnteriorVilao.getEnergia());
```

Depois eu atualizo os atributos do Jogador.oponente só que de algum modo que não entendo EstadoAnteriorVilao recebe as mesmas alterações.

Se puderem me ajudar a entender o que acontece.

Comment: Simples, você não está atribuindo uma "cópia" da variavel estatica, mas sua referencia em memoria, por isso que muda também na variável não estática se alterar o conteudo do objeto da variável estatica.

Comment: Como eu faço pra guardar só o conteúdo da variável e não a sua referência em memoria. Tipo em C quando uso * pra pegar o conteúdo de um ponteiro.

Comment: [Como fazer cópia de objetos em java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60813/28595)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquise por Cloneable

Exemplo:

```
public class Jogador implements Cloneable {

Jogador getClone() {
    try {
        return (Jogador) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

}